# WSO2- MSF4J to parse XML dynamically

Tags: msf4j, wso2-msf4j

I am in a requirement to develop a middleware API on MSF4J framework which shoudl be able to accept XML as input and send a transformed XML back to client? Could see examples with json as input like the below snippet but not with XML anywhere?

How to receive and parse XML dynamically?.

With JSON code :-

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
@POST
@Path("/orderpizza")
public Response post(JsonObject orderDetailsJson) { }
```

P.S- not with XML file in local system.

Comment: Why don't you consume the XML and parse it to an Object? e.g https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/wso2/msf4j/service/TestMicroservice.java#L140

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne - Thanks for your reply. From the reference you have provided, one has to create a bean class with all the tags present in the XML/XSD which has to be modified whenever XSD is updated I believe. But if you look @ the above example (https://medium.com/@mcvidanagama/create-webservice-in-just-2-minutes-with-wso2-microservices-framework-for-java-msf4j-59f5dd72416d), it will import com.google.gson.JsonObject package and then can parse it without having a bean class.